# I am having a problem with Struct identifier is undefined and incompatible declarations for funtions on AVL tree program

Tags: c++, struct, avl-tree

This is the header file for an AVL tree program using a struct. The other private member functions are in my BinaryTree.cpp file and there are no issues there. However, I have discussed further below in the code the issue I am having. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class BinaryTree
{
private:
    struct TreeNode
    {
        string name;
        int krabbyPatty;
        TreeNode* left;
        TreeNode* right;

    };

    TreeNode* root;
    
    // Private member functions
    void insert(TreeNode *&, TreeNode *&);
    void destroySubTree(TreeNode *);;
    void displayInOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void display(TreeNode *ptr, int level);
    void getTotal(TreeNode *nodePtr, int &total);
    void getMost(TreeNode *nodePtr, string& n, int& mostPatties);
    void getLeast(TreeNode *nodePtr, string& n, int& leastPatties);


public:
    // Constructor
    BinaryTree()
    { 

        root = NULL; 
    
    }

    // Destructor
    ~BinaryTree()
    { 
        destroySubTree(root); 
    }

    // Binary tree operations
    void insertNode(string, int);
    int searchNode(string);
    //void remove(string);

    void displayInOrder() const
    {  
        displayInOrder(root); 
    }
    
    void getLeastNumPatties(string&, int&);
    void getMostNumPatties(string&, int&);
    int getTotalNumPatties();
    void displayTree();

    int height(TreeNode *);
    int diff(TreeNode *);
    
    TreeNode r_rotation(TreeNode *);
    TreeNode *l_rotation(TreeNode *);
    TreeNode *lr_rotation(TreeNode *);
    TreeNode *rl_rotation(TreeNode *);
    
    TreeNode* balance(TreeNode *);


};


/*  height:  Find the height of a node and return it    */
int BinaryTree::height(TreeNode *temp) 
{
//WRITE DEFINITION
int h = 0;
if (temp != NULL)
{
    int l_height = height(temp->left);
    int r_height = height(temp->right);
    int max_height = max(l_height, r_height);
    h = max_height + 1;
}
return h;
}


/*  diff:  Find the HEIGHT DIFFERENCE between the left & right subtrees */
int BinaryTree::diff(TreeNode *temp)
{
//WRITE DEFINITION
int l_height = height(temp->left);
int r_height = height(temp->right);
int b_factor= l_height - r_height;
return b_factor;
}
```

The problems begin right here, the error is that TreeNode is undefined and the function name says declaration is incompatible with "BinaryTree::TreeNode *BinaryTree::l_rotation(BinaryTree::TreeNode *)" And this problem is the same for every function from this point on, so I can rinse and repeat to fix the rest. I know this is probably something simple that I am just looking over, however, any help will be appreciated!

```
/*  l_rotation:  Perform LEFT ROTATION on this parent node  */              
TreeNode *BinaryTree::l_rotation(TreeNode *parent)
{
//WRITE DEFINITION
TreeNode *temp;
temp = parent->left;
parent->right = temp->left; //SWITCHING TEAMS (if node exists, NULL otherwise)
temp->left = parent;  //new parent node (move old parent to left)
return temp;
}

/*  r_rotation:  Perform RIGHT ROTATION on this parent node */
TreeNode *BinaryTree::r_rotation(TreeNode *parent)
{
TreeNode *temp;
temp = parent->right;
parent->right = temp->left;
temp->left = parent;
return temp;
}


TreeNode *BinaryTree::lr_rotation(TreeNode *parent)
{
TreeNode *temp;
temp = parent->left;
parent->left = r_rotation(temp);
return r_rotation(parent);
}

/*  rl_rotation:  Perform RIGHT-LEFT ROTATION on this parent node   */
TreeNode *BinaryTree::rl_rotation(TreeNode *parent)
{
//WRITE DEFINITION
TreeNode *temp;
temp = parent->right;
parent->right = l_rotation(temp);
return l_rotation(parent);
}


TreeNode *BinaryTree::balance(TreeNode *temp)
{
//WRITE DEFINITION
 int bal_factor = diff (temp);
if (bal_factor > 1)
{
    if (diff(temp->left()) > 0)  // 2, 1  RIGHT
    {
        temp = r_rotation(temp);
        cout << "\nRIGHT rotation";
    }
    else                            // 2, -1 LEFT-RIGHT
    {
        temp = lr_rotation(temp);
        cout << "\nLEFT-RIGHT rotation";
    }
}
else if (bal_factor < -1)
{
    if (diff (temp->right) > 0) // -2, 1 RIGHT-LEFT
    {
        temp = rl_rotation(temp);
        cout << "\nRIGHT-LEFT rotation";
    }
    else                            // -2, -1 LEFT
    {
        temp = l_rotation(temp);
        cout << "\nLEFT Rotation";
    }
}
return temp;

}





#endif
```

Comment: Make it `BinaryTree::TreeNode* BinaryTree::l_rotation(TreeNode *parent) {...}`

Comment: I've done that and that solved one problem, now it is saying 'TreeNode' does not name a type.

Comment: What line does this new error refer to?

Comment: I think it is referring to the parameter (TreeNode *parent) in all the functions

Comment: I moved all the functions over to my .cpp file and now the error is gone.

Comment: `r_rotation` is declared to return `TreeNode` (without a star), but the definition attemps to return `TreeNode*` (with the star)

Comment: `temp->left()` doesn't make sense as `left` is not a function.